# End process error code -1 if acess to string field of structure

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#define S 10

using namespace std;
struct List
{
    string name;
    bool male;
    int year;
    string addr;
    string diag;
    bool hosp;
};

main()
{
    struct List *l=NULL;
    int n=0;
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        if(!(n%S))
        {
            l=(List*)realloc(l,(n/S+1)*S*sizeof(struct List));
            cout<<"realloc ok\n";
        };
        l[n].male=rand()%2;
        l[n].year=1900+rand()%100;
        l[n].hosp=rand()%2;
        //!l[n].name="abc";
        n++;
        cout<<l[rand()%n].male<<" "<<l[rand()%n].year<<" "<<l[rand()%n].hosp<<endl;
    }
}
```

If l[n].name="abc" remarked then program works fine.
If i try put string value to this field the programm compiled without warnings nay, but crash with error code -1 after first realloc.
Any way to solve it?

Comment: Step through the code in your debugger to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your structure is non-trivial - it contains members of class type, `std::string`, which need to be initialised by calling their constructors - you can't simply allocate raw memory and pretend that contains a valid object.

The simplest solution is to use a type-aware dynamic array

```
std::vector<List> l;
```

which can be resized, perserving its contents, with

```
l.resize((n/S+1)*S);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip! Using "new" operator to allocate this structure will automatically create string object for each field.

```
List *l=new struct List[S];
```

It fix this issue, l[n].name="abc" will works, but it not implements reallocation functional.